# Adding element to existing XML node

Tags: c#

Where am i going wrong???

I have an xml file with OppDetails as a tag already as shown below

```
<OppDetails>
  <OMID>245414</OMID> 
  <ClientName>Best Buy</ClientName> 
  <OppName>International Rate Card</OppName> 
  <CTALinkType>AO,IO,MC,TC</CTALinkType> 
  </OppDetails>
  </OppFact>
```

Now i am trying to add another element to it but getting an error in AppendChild method please help

```
XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("OppDetails");
XmlElement xmlEle = xmlDoc.CreateElement("CTAStartDate");
xmlEle.InnerText = ExcelUtility.GetCTAStartDate();
rootNode.AppendChild(xmlEle);
            xmlDoc.Save("C:\\test.xml");
```

Comment: It would help to know what the error is.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 3):

```
XmlElement xmlEle = xmlDoc.DocumentElement["OppDetails"];
XmlElement eleNew = xmlDoc.CreateElement("CTAStartDate");
eleNew.InnerText = ExcelUtility.GetCTAStartDate();
xmlEle.AppendChild(eleNew);
xmlDoc.Save("C:\\test.xml");
```

Comment: Is this the solution to the problem?

Comment: It would be helpful to mark this as the accepted answer.  Also, if you could provide any details as to why you were able to get this to work when your previous attempt failed it would help others.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell without a full sample, but a common reason for `SelectNodes` / `SelectSingleNode` returning `null` is xml namespaces. If you xml makes use of element namespaces, you'll probably need to use an `XmlNamespaceManager` along with your query, and define a suitable alias for the namespace you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is `rootNode` `null`?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw.aspx) on `SelectSingleNode`:

> The first XmlNode that matches the
>   XPath query or a null reference
>   (Nothing in Visual Basic) if no
>   matching node is found.

If `rootNode` is `null`, it indicates that the node could not be found, and trying to use the null `rootNode` would cause the exception you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you've reported means that you have not located the root element. When `SelectSingleNode` can't find the requested node, it returns `null`. You didn't check for that.

Answer (score 0):

Read root node and add the new element in to the root node. I think you are trying to append in XML document.

Comment: This should be a comment.